# Will my floor safely support 2000 lbs of live load over a 36"x36" area?

Tags: structural-engineering, wood

I'm trying to find out if my floor will safely support a live load for an aquarium in an area that is approximately 36" by 36". the total weight would be about two thousand pounds including water, all contents, the tank, the stand and all components. the house is approximately 20 years old give or take a year. the tank would be placed in the corner of a living room. one wall is an exterior  wall with single 2"x10" joists spaced 16" on center and the other wall is an interior wall with 2"x10" sister joist underneath it. 3/4" sub floor. Basement foundation is poured and the house passed building inspection when we bought it 3 years ago with flying colors.  There is a doorway to the basement so adding a floor Jack or posts to reinforce if needed are out of the question. Should I add cross sections between the joist? Will it be safe the way it is?

Comment: Isn't this the kind of thing you would have to have someone inspect your house to decide? The consequences of failure are catastrophic and will happen suddenly, potentially not immediately either. I'm not sure anyone on here would be willing to answer that given the stakes and the the vagueness of information. That's two grand pianos or a small car in an area several times smaller than either.

Comment: It is not a "live" load. A live load moves , something like a wheeled cart rolling back and forth or a cow walking back and forth, maybe some kind of vibrating machine. I expect the aquarium will just set still. ( Live fish do not count).

Comment: @blacksmith37 *dead load:  This is the weight of everything that is permanent such as the floor joists, walls, piping, ductwork, floor tile, etc.

live load:  This is the weight of everything that you add to the house or apartment when you move in.  Furniture, bookshelves, people, appliances, and of course, your computer and your aquarium(s).* https://badmanstropicalfish.com/articles/article28.html Probably different definitions for different contexts.

Comment: **Live load** - Live load is broken into two parts – a **sustained load**, based on the people and furniture that normally occupy a space, and a **transient or extraordinary load**, based on parties, gatherings, and other less frequent events. https://simplesupports.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/asces-live-load-model/

Comment: Just by engineering judgment, the weight of the aquarium is way beyond the strength of the floor support structure which was normally designed for a live load of 40 psf (for residential building). Depends on the span length, the joists are either need to be resized or sistered with additional joists. Do not take/trust any advice from the web, hire a lincensed structural engineer to plan out for you.

Answer (score 1):

## You won't get this answer via this site

To @DKNGuyen's comment, this is **too complex an issue to resolve remotely**.  We don't know the condition of the joists, the length of span, the methods of joining to the wall structures, nor the strength of the connecting wall.

From just a sniff-test, this is way way too much load to put in a home without having an engineer look at it, in person.  This engineer will be licensed & bonded so you are protected if your house falls down.  The consequences of failure here are too great (don't count on your homeowner's policy covering you if you do something to knock your house down).  My guess is that any engineer will have you strengthen the joists, may change their connections to the wall, and may have the walls themselves strengthened (part of how they stay licensed and bonded).

Answer (score 0):

Your floors are designed for forty pounds live load per square foot. You want to load it by roughly 220 pounds per foot.

Do you think it makes sense?

I have inspected some homes for insurance claims and have seen studs literally curved under excessive loads.

You have to add enough joists under the floor to bring it up to strength. You need to have it checked by an engineer. They may ask you to add lateral support for seismic resistance as well.

Comment: How to you even know what country the OP is in, when you make wild statements like "designed for 40 pounds per square foot." For example UK building regulations specify "150 pounds per square foot over a maximum of 5% of the total floor area". Still not enough for the OP, but we don't build flimsy timber framed houses over here.

Comment: my apologies it was a trap. i just wanted to see how you are doing @alephzero.

Comment: @alephzero UK most certainly has timber framed houses and they are pretty much built just like they are in the states.

Comment: @alephzero I assume the implication is that they have a lot of older buildings built with better wood when it was available.